# Define a function to execute multiple commands

Tags: init-file, debugging

Here is part of my `init.el`:

```
(defun xx-devanagari-script ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (face-remap-add-relative 'default :family "Lohit Devanagari")
    (text-scale-increase)
    (text-scale-increase)))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c d") 'xx-devanagari-script)
```

All I am trying to do is change the font of the current buffer to 'Lohit Devanagari' and increase the text scale twice.

It changes the font. But the text scale does not increase. It also produces an error:

> Wrong number of arguments: (1 . 1), 0

How do I get my first elisp function going?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few hints in your description:

1. It changes the font. So your `face-remap-add-relative` call is working
2. It doesn't change the scale, so the `text-scale-increase` calls are not working
3. Emacs reports an error: wrong number of arguments.

Look at the help for `text-scale-increase` (via `C-h f text-scale-increase`):

> (text-scale-increase INC)
>
> Increase the height of the default face in the current buffer by INC steps.
>   If the new height is other than the default, ‘text-scale-mode’ is enabled.

`text-scale-increase` requires an argument, and you didn't provide it. Also, this argument means you don't need to call it twice, you can call it once with `2` as the argument:

```el
(defun xx-devanagari-script ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (face-remap-add-relative 'default :family "Lohit Devanagari")
    (text-scale-increase 2)))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c d") 'xx-devanagari-script)
```

Comment: Thanks. That was perfect. I must remember to look up the extensive documentation provided with emacs. :)